# Which of all available circuit simulators provide the most accurate results?

Tags: simulation, spice, accuracy

After learning a lot more, I've come to the conclusion that simulators are in fact limited. Let's use a phase shift oscillator as an example. In simulation, It worked perfectly(in nearly every configuration), in reality I had to add 3 more stages. In simulation the waveforms lowest amplitude is 1 volt in reality it's 0. So in the words of the late Bob Pease, "I program in solder", lol. The Simulators are great for small circuits or IC design. Larger circuits have a greater chance of discrepancy. Not to devalue the SPICE simulators, but I've learned to sim a small sub circuit and build it to be certain it will work.

I must also add The schematic I originally posted was awful. At this point I would never post a design like that(I laugh at most of my old designs), but it's the learning process.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to respect Darlington configurations" is very ambiguous. In what sense? Any power transistor will blow up if the die temperature gets high enough even if the collector current and collector-emitter voltages are within spec.

Comment: Any simulator will be inaccurate if the circuit or models are wrong, and that's what this sounds like to me.

Comment: As hinted above, this is likely an X-Y problem. Post your schematic that "simulated fine" and doesn't work in real life. At least, that's what I think I'm reading, that's also not fully clear to me.

Comment: You guys aren't getting me. I'll put a schematic together real quick and show you what I mean.

Comment: There's no way LTSPICE DOESN'T work correctly for Darlington configurations.  That would be such a fundamental issue that the simulator would be useless.  Of course it may not work in a particular case due to the circuit models, or convergence in a larger circuit or any number or reasons, but it's not a limitation of the simulator in general.

Comment: Hspice is pretty industry standard.  No real IC companies use LTSpice outside of maybe very low volume

Comment: Agree with JohnD. LTSpice works fine for Darlingtons configs. I'm more certain that you don't realize that such devices vary extremely widely and didn't properly design to account for the fact -- depending instead on some single figure that LTspice spit out. Imagine designing a BJT amplifier with a single biasing resistor to the + rail based entirely on some "assumed" value for beta, taken from the LTspice model being used. Would work in LTspice. But NO WAY would it work in practice. That's my bet.

Comment: An _accurate_ spice would conserve charge. I don't know of any in the commercial space that do it.

Comment: I can't find 'MJE13' in LTspice. Where can I get this model?

Comment: You can find the model here [LTwiki](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Standard.bjt)

Comment: Are you certain the Q1 emitter is connected to the Q2 base? Draw them separated a bit and use an actual wire segment to connect them.

Comment: Or review the SPICE netlist to confirm the connection.

Comment: @The Photon: There's another render Just [F8] stretched the circuit and changed the R1 to 1.5M which is exacty the value I used when I powered the chip, etc. in the real world.  For it to run an oscillator properly I have to use a 500K value in the simulator.

Comment: What does an oscillator have to do with anything? You never mentioned any oscillator in your question.

Comment: Dude that's just an example circuit I put together for someone who asked to see a schematic example. I play with this program all day. I'm a student. I made the regulator just to do it because I'd just learned about darlingtons and testing it out blowing the heads off of transistors for fun just to prove that the software was off.

Comment: "of course theres a voltage drop across the transistors but c'mon." C'mon yourself. So far you haven't actually told us anything about your failures. You've disavowed your example ("Dude. That's just an example"), so we have no way to tell what might have gone wrong. Provide a real example, and give us real Spice outputs and give us real voltages and currents which don't agree with the model. For instance, your example with 340 volts will cause the transistors to dissipate more than 750 watts if the zener works correctly. Stop being coy and tell us what really happens.

Comment: If cost wasn't an issue I'd hire me LOL (or a bunch of electro-monkeys to build stuff and test it) BUT the point is that engineers use a sim to save cost i.e. save PCB iterations so I think you are missing the point entirely.

Comment: @jbord39 *"No real IC companies use LTSpice"* mmmh... Linear Technology, maybe?

Comment: Mike Engelhardt maintains the LTspice software. He has said that they pay him to keep it updated for in-house IC use. He doesn't distribute their internal models and isn't paid to keep LTspice filled to the brim with competing IC and/or convenient discrete models to keep the hoi polloi happy. So LTspice is lacking in models for the rest of us. Mike keeps up on the stuff LT cares about (for internal use by IC designers and for their marketing department to sell Linear's power and opamp products.)

Comment: Since you don't want to admit that your model is broken and you now assume that the simulation tool everyone has been used successfully over the last 40 years is broken, your question as it stands is now off-topic.

Comment: Nah, I didn't know the model was broken. I got it off of the LTWiki. Relax why are people so rude here, I like the software VERY MUCH. I just don't want to get into to complex a design and find out that a miscalculated value is gonna make a $25 MOSFET pop.

Comment: @iuppiter You actively _invite_ off-topic comments and downvotes when you attack users in your question. I've removed the offensive and off-topic bits from your question.

Comment: @pipe cool, I was just a little aggravated because the question became about the linear regulator, which I got from nut's n' volts site. I really wanted to know just which sim is best at the render and it would be nice if it were easier to incorporate libraries. As you can see by the comments, the schematic kept getting attacked. I didn't even post the schematic with the first post. someone wanted to see it. The question started out very simple. I couldn't have put it better. thank you

Comment: @iuppiter Fair enough, I didn't look closely at the edit records, I just inferred what had happened from the comments.

Comment: @pipe, Spehro Pefhany did completely answer the original question, between the answer and comments. He explained how the models work and I understand where the issues exist, read the comment list. That answer applies to ALL simulators.

Comment: @dim: Except, they use their own in-house version which almost certainly is not the same as the free version they release.  And if you think that any real IC companies are spending upwards of 10's of millions for masks/fabrication and using a freeware simulation tool, you are fooling yourself silly ... The freeware LTSpice is a great marketing tool for their consumers because they also release the models for their own IC's for LTSpice.  But that does not make it industry standard.  And unless the company is using LTSpice modules it would be very unlikely they use LTSpice for tapeout.

Comment: @jboard39 I agree with you totally, hence the question. I personally think cadence is far superior and is much better supported by component manufacturers. 3rd party library import is very easy. LT is obviously a marketing tool. All of LT's newest models are included, the old school components and some crap models from other manufacturers so that the software is actually usable. I must admit development is fast, there's no denying that, but the lack of GOOD support from other component manufacturers leave much to be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who knows what those transistors actually are? - the Chinese even mark TO92 parts with similar numbers.

You are just wasting time with dubious parts and experimental technique.

In any case you are way outside the SOA - the pass transistor will only be good for 0.1ms at 1A/300V Vce after which it will prolly go short, at least briefly until the bonding wires fuse, Read up on second breakdown and safe operating area- it is much less than the current you could expect from thermal considerations, which in turn is a heck of a lot less than 1A at 320V = 320W. Maybe 20mA, which will still require a good heat sink, even if the parts were genuine.

By the way, Zener Pd is Zener current * Zener voltage, not the full supply voltage (unless you short the resistor, in which case something dies).

Comment: Thank you Spehro, I will do further research and refrain from using cheap Chinese parts in the future, because these transistors did work in practice and did supply a load with no sink for as long as I wanted, but as you said, once the current is excessive they do explode. I was under the assumption that zener Pd was the e * i,  being the full charge supplied to the zener which in is .23w @500k and also with the thinking that the zener clips the input voltage to the desired reference point. I guess I've been looking at it from a total Q/sec perspective.

Comment: I somehow do not think I will get an answer to my actual question here, but you did answer a question I had in mind a while back about the regulator and why the transistors exploded in the darlington config, when I was playing with that circuit, so I'll give you credit for the answer. I know you're knowledgeable, I've seen your Rep., and you got me past a serious caveat in a previous question. The Idea was originally to power the primary for an SMPS. I found that regulator on Nuts n' Volts' website. I'm currently experimenting with an inductive solution. I'm still learning the physics of EE.

Comment: The situation in your original circuit with no load (or up to a few tens of mA) is completely different from that with a 1A load. Models often do not cover things out of normal operating range such as breakdown, second breakdown, exploding and so on, though there is nothing impossible in creating such a model it would not be useful for most users and would run more slowly (and often simulation speed is important with real circuits).

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that the simulation speed slows drastically with circuit complexity. Correct me if I'm misunderstanding you. However, I gather from your comment that any sim would render the same results if the model is not coded with the destruction parameters, and it would drastically slow sim speed to do so, so I should just use common sense when designing circuits being sure to adhere to information provided by component datasheets and at prototype time I should be okay. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm a systems developer. Can I write my own models? because I have some Hi-Lo Drivers(among other ICs) I really need in Sim and if I can code them based on datasheet parameters that would be awesome.

Comment: There are some subtleties. The functions need to to be smooth or you'll end up with it not converging. The simulators are actually solving differential equations. Subscribe to the LTSpice list for lots of wisdom. Also the models work to typical parameters not guaranteed-and that information may not be provided on the datasheet.

Comment: Okay, I will do some research, thank you the information and for your patience in, answering all of my questions.

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed your circuit does not work as you originally presented it.
$$ \frac{320 \rm{V}}{500 \rm{k\Omega}}\approx 0.7 \rm{mA}$$
and apparently this is not enough to get your zener producing the full 24 V output voltage, and provide the necessary (even if small) base current to Q1 also. The current gain (\$\beta\$) of MJE13003 is only 40, therefore about 1.2 mA base current is required at Q1, even in Darlington configuration.

I reduced R1 to 50 kohms and it works as expected, output voltage about 22 V. The problem is not that the tool is not accurate, the problem is you didn't give your zener and darlington enough current to work with.

Comment: in reality used 1 and 2 meg and did get about 22V with a load, you're off by about 20V, i'm using 1/4W zeners and do the calculation. P=V*I 340*700uA = .23W

Comment: @iuppiter were you actually using MJE13003's? Because at least the On Semi datasheet gives 40 as the **max** gain (for 0.5 A I_c, maybe it'll be a bit bigger in Q1, but hopefully not too much...LTSpice shows beta of 43 in the original circuit)

Comment: Yup, that's whats bugging me out.

Comment: You know you can trigger a darlington with your finger using the right transistors. The MJE is a fast switching power transistor.

Comment: Well you've got me stumped then. Is your 500 kohm resistor rated for 300 V?

Comment: They're the blue metal film ones you get from amazon. I've tested the current at the resistor diode junction and it is 700uA, but it works. Its the total charge of .23Cu/sec. is enough to get a 1/4w(max) diode going.

Comment: If you're buying components from Amazon, who knows what you're actually getting.

Comment: Yo man I got those transistors on ebay from china, they could be bootlegged, lol.  But they do live up to the datasheet as far as voltage, maybe whats happening is Q1 isn't at its point of saturation but is on which in turn puts Q2 into full saturation, which is why I added the second transistor in the first place. I was making a linear regulator to power some experimental dc-dc  converter i was making, just learning stuff

Comment: LMAO, I do have a multi-meter and a cheap oscilloscope

Comment: A multimeter isn't going to tell you whether a resistor can withstand 300 V.

Comment: a  multimeter will however tell me the resistance of my resistors to insure accuracy. I'm using. I have yet to see a voltage rating on a resistor. I've used 1/4w resistors to get a .20w of P from a High voltage power source without issue. The resistor didn't even get warm.